# Change state of another component in React

Tags: reactjs

As of now, I have a class generating all the list for a component that will be called multiple times. However is it possible for the user to only select one item with the same ID?

```
  class Skills extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.img = props.src
    this.name = props.name
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <Row>
          <Image src={this.img} style={skillIcon} rounded />
          <div>
          <h4>{this.name}</h4>
          <ul className="sul">
            <li id="lvl 1">1</li>
            <li id="lvl 2">2</li>
            <li id="lvl 3">3</li>
            <li id="lvl 4">4</li>
            <li id="lvl 5">5</li>
            <li id="lvl 6">6</li>
            <li id="lvl 7">7</li>
            <li id="lvl 8">8</li>
            <li id="lvl 9">9</li>
            <li id="lvl 10">10</li>
            <li id="lvl 11">11</li>
            <li id="lvl 12">12</li>
            <li id="lvl 13">13</li>
            <li id="lvl 14">14</li>
            <li id="lvl 15">15</li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          
          </Row>
        </div>
          
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

For example, if li with id lvl 1 is selected, the next time someone clicks on another lvl 1 li of the same regenerated component, the previous selection would be deselected.

Comment: do you want to highlight your selection or store somewhere else like in an array?

Comment: I want to highlight it and then later read what was selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store user selection in state and update state when user selected another item.

State can be handled in two ways.

1. Classic Class components way

```
// its better to have a array with levels 

const levels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
class Skills extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selection:null
       
    }
    this.img = props.src
    this.name = props.name
  }

  render() {
   const {selection} = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <Row>
          <Image src={this.img} style={skillIcon} rounded />
          <div>
          <h4>{this.name}</h4>
          <ul className="sul">
           {levels.map((level) => {
              const isSelected = selection === level;
              return (
                <li
                  id={`lvl ${level}`}
                  key={level}
                  onClick={() => setSelection(level)}
                  style={{
                    padding: isSelected ? 10 : 2,
                    backgroundColor: isSelected ? 'red' : 'white',
                  }}

                >

                  {level}
                </li>
              );
            })}
           
          </ul>
          </div>
          
          </Row>
        </div>
          
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

2. new functional hooks way

```
function Skills() {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState(null);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <img src={img} />
        <div>
          <h4>{name}</h4>
          <ul className="sul">
            {levels.map((level) => {
              const isSelected = selection === level;
              return (
                <li
                  id={`lvl ${level}`}
                  key={level}
                  onClick={() => setSelection(level)}
                  style={{
                    padding: isSelected ? 10 : 2,
                    backgroundColor: isSelected ? 'red' : 'white',
                  }}

                >

                  {level}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>

    </>
  );
}
```

### Not related but i just wanna suggest

#### 1. If  `src` is not dynamic , just assign a const variable assigned like

```
const LOGO_URL = "url to logo"
const logoStyle = {
...some css
}
<Image src={LOGO_URL} style={logoStyle} />
```

#### 2. If this array of level numbers is dynamic (some api or something) , get it from props

```
function Skill(props){
  const  { levels  }  = props

   return (
      <>
        {levels.map(i => {
            ...do anything 
        })}
      </>
    )
}
```

### **update**: when you need to update parent State from child component

```
function RootComponent() {

 const [rootState,setRootState] = useState(null)
 return (
  <SkillsOrAnyComponent updateState={setRootState}  />
 
)



function SkillsOrAnyComponent(props){
  const { updateState } = props 
  const changeMainState = (val) => {
     updateState(val)
  }
  return ...some jsx
```

}
}

Comment: The functional hook works amazing, however, I want to update another instance of the same component and not within the same component

Comment: Then you need a prop function . check updated answer